# Why do the stars in the galaxy core move so fast?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, milky-way, newtonian-mechanics

There are a bunch of stars orbiting the black hole in the center of [our galaxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milky_Way).

These stars move at huge speed. Why do we see this? Why do the black hole not impose any noticeable time dilation on these stars?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Great question Lucas.
The velocity of an object in orbit around a massive body can be expressed roughly as

$v(R)\sim \sqrt{ \frac{GM}{R}}$

The closer you are to the mass (e.g. the black-hole), the bigger v(r) becomes.  It turns out, for a black-hole like the one at the galactic center, with stars about 100 AU away.... they travel at about 500 km/s---fast!

[image]

Now, the effects of general relativity are only significant when you're near the event horizon.  In this case, even though the stars are relatively 'close' (about $10^{15}$ cm), they're still almost about 1000 times further away than the event-horizon!  And so the effects of general relativity (e.g. time dilation) are very very small (in this case, currently unobservable at all).